# Substituting multiple repetitive strings in pandas dataframe with consecutive respective numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

I asked [this question for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256470/substituting-multiple-repetitive-strings-in-r-dataframe-with-consecutive-respect), but now trying to do the same in Python.

I have a dataframe with 10000 rows:

```
Author  Value
aaa     111
aaa     112
bbb     156
bbb     165
ccc     543
ccc     256
```

Each author has 4 rows, so I have 2500 authors.

I would like to substitute all strings into numeric values. Ideally with `tidyverse`.

Expected output:

```
Author  Value
1       111
1       112
2       156
2       165
3       543
3       256
---------
2500    451
2500    234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Author'] = pd.factorize(df['Author'])[0] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, cumsum the boolean values of consecutive column values

```
df['Author'] = (df['Author']!=df['Author'].shift()).cumsum()
```